# Google Chrome, JQuery - show doesn't work with autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have input element with autofocus:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if(isset($name)) {echo $name;} ?>" autofocus="autofocus"/>
```

and JS to show div element when input comes to focus:

```
var forma = $('form#mali_oglas input'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]');    
    forma.on('focus', function(){
    pomoc.show();
 });
```

This is working in FireFox but it is not working in Chrome (when another input field comes to focus **pomoc** is shown). What seems to be a problem?

Comment: is the other field in the same form? Because you bind your onfocus function on the form, not the specific field.

Comment: @primavera133 Not on the form but to all input fields within the form.

Comment: There are few more input fields in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the focus function to every element of type **input** in the form with id **mali_oglas**. If you want to catch only the input above, you should use:

```
var forma = $('#name'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]');    
    forma.on('focus', function(){
    pomoc.show();
 });
```

P.S: Also a good idea to focus an element on load is this (because autofocus is not cross-browser supported):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name').focus();
});
```